# Need to limit connection limit for a database in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, configuration, database-connection

I have set max_connection = 2000 into my postgresql.conf file. However, I have 10 databases on this server and each one of them is using a few number of connections from available connection. I need to limit number of connection for each one of them. For example, for abc database , I want , it should use only 100 connections,not more than that. Is there any way to limit number of connection for each database on a particular server for postgres. Any immediate response will be appreciated.

-Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set connection limit per database by running an `ALTER` command on the database and setting `CONNECTION LIMIT`, like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db_name CONNECTION LIMIT 100;
```

For more information have a look [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html).